# hidden token is displayed on page in IE10

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer-10, jsp-tags, hidden-field

I am looking for help(suggestions) on what can be changed in the code below syntax wise or otherwise to ensure that hidden token is not displayed(hidden) in any browser.i don't have a problem with the code below in IE7,Chrome or Firefox.IE10 on the other hand doesn't like something and the hidden token is displayed on the screen

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>

 <script type="text/javascript">
WF.onWRIAReady({},
function() {
    WF.onDOMReady(addCsrfToken);
});

function addCsrfToken() {
    var csrf = '<c:out value="${sessionScope['csrfToken']}" />';
    //alert(csrf);
    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
        currentForm = document.forms[i];
        addHiddenInputField(currentForm, "csrfToken", csrf);
    }
}

function addHiddenInputField(formElement, fieldName, fieldValue) {
    var existingElement = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < formElement.elements.length; i++) {
        if (formElement.elements[i].name == fieldName) {
            existingElement = formElement.elements[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (existingElement == null) {
        var inputElement = document.createElement("input");
        inputElement.setAttributeNode(createHtmlAttribute("type", "hidden"));
        inputElement.setAttributeNode(createHtmlAttribute("name", fieldName));
        inputElement.setAttributeNode(createHtmlAttribute("id", fieldName));
        inputElement.setAttributeNode(createHtmlAttribute("value", fieldValue));
        formElement.appendChild(inputElement);
    }
    else {
        existingElement.value = fieldValue;
    }
}

function createHtmlAttribute(name, value) {
   var attribute = document.createAttribute(name);
   attribute.nodeValue = value;
   return attribute;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help with my question

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in really old versions of IE where you can't make an input and change it's `type` with `setAttribute`. Using the direct notation *should* work.

```
var input = document.createElment("input");
input.type = "hidden";
```